# ggplot2: Display values in stacked bar charts (Values are hidden behind bars)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked, patchwork

I am having troubles to display the y-values in stacked bar charts as they appear but are displayed behind the bars and hence not visible.

My goal is to display the values within the stacked bars so they are visible. Any help would be highly apprciated. Thank you very much!

The values that should be displayed in the respective stack of every bars are the following:

```
RAIH <- c(11,13,10,5,7,10,8,4,11,11,4,3,7,9,3,2,11,15,10,6,11,13,14,7,8,16,10,7,6,8,6,4,11,8,5,3,10,12,3,1,11,10,5,2,10,11,4,2,17,12,7,6,9,10,5,3,18,17,7,7,14,11,6,2)
```

I used following code to display the values, which is also included in the main code.

```
geom_text(aes(label = RAIH), size = 3, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

The rest of my code for creating the graph is:

```
 library(ggplot2)
  library(patchwork)
  library(dplyr)
  library(plotrix)
  library(plyr)

     ploughed1 <- Data_GG %>%
    dplyr::select(Tillage, RAI_N, Mulch, compost, Ferment, Horizont, mean, se) %>%
    filter(Tillage == "Ploughed", Mulch=="No Mulch") %>%
    group_by(Tillage)
  
  ploughed2 <- Data_GG %>%
    dplyr::select(Tillage, RAI_N, Mulch, compost, Ferment, Horizont, mean, se) %>%
    filter(Tillage == "Ploughed", Mulch=="Mulch") %>%
    group_by(Tillage)
  
  
  reduced1 <- Data_GG %>%
    dplyr::select(Tillage, RAI_N, Mulch, compost, Ferment, Horizont, mean, se) %>%
    filter(Tillage == "Reduced",  Mulch=="No Mulch") %>%
    group_by(Tillage) 
  
  reduced2 <- Data_GG %>%
    dplyr::select(Tillage, RAI_N, Mulch, compost, Ferment, Horizont, mean, se) %>%
    filter(Tillage == "Reduced",  Mulch=="Mulch") %>%
    group_by(Tillage) 

     plot_fun <- function(x, title) {
    ggplot(arrange(x, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_N, label = RAIH, 
                                     fill = factor(Horizont, levels = c("4", "3", "2", "1")))) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
      geom_text(aes(label = RAIH), size = 3, 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
      scale_fill_manual(name ="Soil layer (cm)", 
                        values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600", "#663300", "#000000"),
                        labels = c("22,5 - 30", "15 - 22,5", "7,5 - 15", "0 - 7,5")) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      ylim(0, 100) +
      theme_bw() +
      facet_wrap(~compost) +
      theme(
        strip.text = element_text(size = 6),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"),
        plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,1)
      ) +
      geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
      labs(x = "Ferment", y = "RAI", fill = "Horizon", title = title)
  }
  
  remove_y <- theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
        
    remove_x <- theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank())
  
  p <- list(
    plot_fun(ploughed1, "P-"),
    plot_fun(ploughed2, "P+") + remove_y + remove_x,
    plot_fun(reduced1, "RT-") + remove_y + remove_x,
    plot_fun(reduced2, "RT+") + remove_y + remove_x
  )
  wrap_plots(p, nrow = 1) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY48s.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `geom_label()` rather than `geom_text()`?

Comment: The issue is probably that you overplot your labels with the geom_col at the end of your plotting function. Hence, try with adding geom_text after geom_col.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.